A good way of handling MonoBehaviour initialization in Unity?
Recently, I've been experimenting with different ways of initializing MonoBehaviours (since constructors are not an option), and I reached a solution that I am mostly satisfied with, but there are a couple of issues left. And I'd like some suggestions on how to address these issues.
I use the following Interfaces to "make a MonoBehaviour Initializable":
One for initialization with parameters:
public interface IInitializable<in TData>
{
    void Initialize(TData data);
}  

And one for initialization without parameters:
public interface IInitializable
{
    void Initialize();
}

The idea is that you can input a struct or class to be used as TData for the initialization, for example:
public readonly struct FooClassInitData
{
    public FooClassInitData(int value1, string value2)
    {
        Value1 = value1;
        Value2 = value2;
    }

    public readonly int Value1;
    public readonly string Value2;
}

Now, my main problems with this approach are:

I haven't found a way to make the Initialize method return the implementing object, it would be nice to initialize and store the object in the same line.

Because Unity still uses C# 9.0 and cannot use IsExternalInit ;( I can't get rid of the empty constructor on the struct, and I also cannot turn the struct into a record.

The most obvious issue with this approach is that, there is nothing to prevent you from initializing the same MonoBehaviour multiple times (A bool could be added to check if the object was already initialized, but you'd have to always update that bool on the implementations, which would be tedious and add a ton of repetition to the codebase.


I know this is kind of a big topic, so my concrete question is:
"Is there a better and/or standardized way of handling initialization on MonoBehaviours?"

Ultimately, everything is an object; and if using it as an "is" or "as" type saves writing a bunch of code, it's worth considering. You can pass an arbitrary number of objects using "params" or a "bag" class in your calls.

I assume you don't want to do this by putting the already-initialized bool/check in an abstract base class deriving from MonoBehaviour, because these initializable components need to use several different inheritance paths. So let's see how far we can get with the interface...


I haven't found a way to make the Initialize method return the implementing object, it would be nice to initialize and store the object in the same line.


We can achieve this via the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern:
public interface IInitializable<TSelf>
{
    TSelf Initialize();
}


public class TestBehaviour : MonoBehaviour, IInitializable<TestBehavior> {

    int _internalState;

    TestBehaviour Initialize() {
        _internalState = 1;
        return this;
    }
}

You can extend this to types that need an input for initialization:
public interface IInitializable<TSelf, in TData>
{
    TSelf Initialize(TData data);
}

I don't have a good solution to point 2. It's a bit annoying/redundant to write out the constructor for a readonly struct, but at least it's something you usually only do once, in one place, rather than something that demands cognitive cycles spread over the whole codebase.
As for 3, avoiding accidental re-initialization, I don't know if this is a "better" way, but you could use a small wrapper struct to help you keep track of whether a reference points to an initialized or uninitialized component.
First, we name our actual initialization method something that reminds us we probably shouldn't call it directly (and is easy to search for to validate whether we're breaking that rule):
public interface IInitializable<TSelf> {
    Initialized<TSelf> INTERNAL_Initialize();
}

Then we make a pair of structs to hold a reference and mark whether or not it's already initialized. These tiny wrappers end up just the size of the original reference, so we don't add any extra storage overhead this way.
public readonly struct Initialized<T> {
    public readonly T content;
    public Initialized(T toWrap) {content = toWrap;}

    public static implicit operator T(Initialized<T> wrapper) => wrapper.content;
}

public struct Uninitialized<T> where T:IInitializable<T> {
    T _content;

    public Uninitialized(T toWrap) {_content = toWrap;}

    public Initialized<T> Initialize() {
         Assert.IsNotNull(_content, "Attempt to re-initialize already-initialized behaviour");

         // This is the only place we'll allow a call to the INTERNAL version.
         var initialized = _content.INTERNAL_Initialize();
         _content = null; // Hollow-out this wrapper so we're not reused.
         return initialized; 
    }
}

To make the code a little less verbose, we can give ourselves some extension methods to easily apply these wrappers:
public static class Initialization {
    public static Initialized<T> AsInitialized<T>(this T input) where T:IInitializable<T> {
        return new Initialized<T>(input);
    }

    public static Uninitialized<T> AsUninitialized<T>(this T input) where T:IInitializable<T> {
        return new Uninitialized<T>(input);
    }
}

An initializable behaviour could look like this:
public class ToInit : MonoBehaviour, IInitializable<ToInit>
{
    public Initialized<ToInit> INTERNAL_Initialize() {
        return this.AsInitialized();
    }

    public void DoSomethingOnceInitialized() {}
}

And creating/caching an uninitialized reference to it, then later initializing it, could look like:
IEnumerator InitTest() {

    GameObject spawn = new GameObject("Test object");

    // We can immediately wrap the reference so we can't accidentally
    // use it before initializing it.
    var uninitialized = spawn.AddComponent<ToInit>().AsUninitialized();
    // Type is Uninitialized<ToInit> but we don't have to write that here.

    // Some other stuff happens between creation and initialization...
    yield return null;

    var initialized = DoSomeInitialization(ref uninitialized);
    // Type is Initialized<ToInit>, and uninitialized now cannot be reused.

    // Now we can access the underlying component's methods.
    initialized.content.DoSomethingOnceInitialized();
}

Initialized<ToInit> DoSomeInitialization(ref Uninitialized<ToInit> uninitialized) {
    // Imagine there's some more complicated initialization work here...
    return uninitialized.Initialize();
}

(This extends to the versions with input data, omitted here for brevity)
It's some extra typing here, but it lets you clearly mark whether a reference or function parameter is holding an uninitialized component that needs initialization, or one that has definitely already been initialized. You can skip the Initialized<T> wrapper and reduce the verbosity if your codebase lets you standardize the convention that any naked component reference is always already-initialized, and uninitialized ones will always be wrapped.
The approach above will prevent you from accidentally initializing the same Uninitialized<T> reference twice, but if you copy that reference (say, sending the same uninitialized variable to multiple methods that might each try to initialize it without telling you), then it won't save you. You can solve that by promoting the struct to a class at the cost of an extra heap allocation and pointer hop. But I think this is easy to avoid: any function that takes an uninitialized parameter really ought to result in initializing it, otherwise there's not much it can do with that handle.
